# Time between two dates except weekends

Tags: python, datetime

I need a function to calculate time in seconds between two dates except weekend days, something that will work like this:

```
# friday 9 PM
start_date = datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 18, 21, 0, 0)

# monday 3 AM
end_date = datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 21, 3, 0, 0)

# should return 6 hours
time = time_between_two_dates_except_weekends(start_date, end_date)
```

I implemented my own function, which is works, but it seems unnecessarily huge and complicated. I think it can be more simpler.

```
import datetime

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from dateutil.rrule import DAILY, rrule

def time_between_two_dates_except_weekends(start_date, end_date):

    WEEKEND_DAYS = [5, 6]

    result = datetime.timedelta()

    if all([start_date.year == end_date.year, start_date.month == end_date.month, start_date.day == end_date.day]):
         result += datetime.timedelta(seconds = (end_date-start_date).seconds )
         return result

    day_after_start_date = start_date + relativedelta(days=1)
    day_after_start_date = day_after_start_date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)

    day_before_end_date = end_date - relativedelta(days=1)

    if start_date.weekday() not in WEEKEND_DAYS:
        result += datetime.timedelta(seconds = (day_after_start_date - start_date).total_seconds())

    dates_range = rrule(
        DAILY,
        byhour=0,
        byminute=0,
        bysecond=0,
        dtstart=day_after_start_date,
        until=day_before_end_date
    )

    for date in dates_range:
        if date.weekday() not in WEEKEND_DAYS:
            result += datetime.timedelta(seconds=24 * 60 * 60)

    if end_date.weekday() not in WEEKEND_DAYS:
        end_date_beginning = end_date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
        result += datetime.timedelta(seconds = (end_date - end_date_beginning).total_seconds())

    return result
```

Is there any way to improve this?

**UPD.** turned out, not only my code is complicated but return incorrect result in some corner cases (for example when weekend day is passed for either the start or the end date). I recommend to just use code from correct answer below

Comment: Please take this to the Code review group.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the Code Review StackExchange. https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can make your code shorter by reducing the weekend checks on the end of your code by adding the byweekday=range(5) parameter to your rrule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from datetime import timedelta
def diff(s, e):
    _diff = (end_date - start_date)
    while s < e:
        if s.weekday() in {5, 6}:
            _diff -= timedelta(days=1)
        s += timedelta(days=1)
    return timedelta(seconds=_diff.total_seconds())
```

If your dates can end or start on a weekend we need to move them to the next monday which we can use a helper function to do:

```
from datetime import timedelta

def helper(d):
   if d.weekday() == 5:
        d += timedelta(days=1)
    return d.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

def diff(s, e):
    if e.weekday() in {5, 6}:
        e = helper(e)
    if s.weekday() in {5, 6}:
        s = helper(s)
    _diff = (e - s)
    while s < e:
        if s.weekday() in {5, 6}:
            _diff -= timedelta(days=1)
        elif s.weekday() == 0:
            s += timedelta(days=4)
        s += timedelta(days=1)
    return timedelta(seconds=_diff.total_seconds())
```

Still runs a nice bit faster:

```
In [57]: timeit time_between_two_dates_except_weekends(start_date,end_date)
10 loops, best of 3: 95.5 ms per loop

In [58]: timeit diff(start_date,end_date)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.4 ms per loop

In [59]: diff(start_date,end_date)
Out[59]: datetime.timedelta(7699, 9300)

In [60]:  time_between_two_dates_except_weekends(start_date,end_date)
Out[60]: datetime.timedelta(7699, 9300)
```

Just doing the math:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

def helper(d):
    if d.weekday() == 5:
        d += timedelta(days=1)
    return d.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)


def diff(s, e):
    weekend = {5, 6}
    both = e.weekday() in weekend and s.weekday() in weekend
    is_weekend = e.weekday() in {5, 6} or s.weekday() in {5, 6}
    if e.weekday() in weekend:
        e = helper(e)
    if s.weekday() in weekend:
        s = helper(s)
    _diff = (e - s)
    wek = _diff.days / 7 * 2 + is_weekend - both
    if s.weekday() > e.weekday() and not is_weekend:
        wek += 2
    return timedelta(seconds=_diff.total_seconds()) - timedelta(wek)
```

Which runs quite a bit faster:

```
In [2]: start_date = datetime(2016, 02, 29, 21, 25, 0)

In [3]: end_date = datetime(2045, 9, 02, 03, 56, 0)

In [4]: timeit diff(start_date,end_date)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.8 µs per loop

In [5]: diff(start_date,end_date)
Out[5]: datetime.timedelta(7699, 9300)
```

Comment: great! exactly what i was hoping for

Comment: Actually, scratch that, what should happen if a weekend day is passed for either the start of the end, should it raise an error?

Comment: I think `end_date` should be `e` and `start_date` should be `s`.

Comment: Also, here's the one-liner version: `timedelta(seconds=((e - s) - timedelta(days=sum([1 for x in range((e - s).days) if (s + timedelta(days=x)).weekday() in {5, 6}]))).total_seconds())`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham "what should happen if a weekend day is passed for either the start of the end" - i guess function should always return time, so 0 seconds is fine. By the way, mine implementation actually return incorrect result in this case.

Comment: Yes, yours would also return an extra day when you pass two times from the same date or two identical date and times. Something else you may want is to make sure the start date is before the end date or you will get negative output which may or not be the desired

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta, MO, SA

def time_between_two_dates_except_weekends(start_date, end_date):
    weekend = set([5, 6])

    if start_date.weekday() in weekend:
        start_date += relativedelta(weekday=MO(1))
        start_date = start_date.replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0)

    if end_date.weekday() in weekend:
        # One microsecond before Saturday at midnight.
        end_date = end_date + relativedelta(weekday=SA(-1)) - datetime.timedelta(microsecond=1)
        end_date = end_date.replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0) 

    number_of_weekends = (end_date - start_date).days / 7    
    if start_date.weekday() > end_date.weekday():
        number_of_weekends += 1

    return end_date - start_date -  datetime.timedelta(days=(number_of_weekends * 2)) 

start_date = datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 22, 14, 24, 29, 894810)
end_date = datetime.datetime.today()

print time_between_two_dates_except_weekends(start_date, end_date)
```

First, if the start or end dates are on the weekends, round them to the previous Friday or next Monday, then consider these two cases:

- Full weeks intervening
- Partial weeks intervening (there will only be one of these)

The full weeks case is easy, just take out two days for each week.

In the case of a partial week, notice that if the `weekday()` of the end date is greater than the `weekday()` of the start date, the number must "wrap around" and there must be a weekend intervening.